# Noty jQuery plugin buttons on confirmation

Tags: jquery, plugins

I tried adding buttons to a noty confirm, however it seems to not work, any ideas why?

I took the code from noty's website under the subsection buttons:

http://needim.github.io/noty/

The alert seems to work fine without the buttons, it's just that when attempting to add buttons, nothing will show up!

Here's the code:

```
function Sure()
{
    var n = noty({
        text: 'Are you sure?',
        type: 'confirm',
        dismissQueue: false,
        layout: 'center',
        theme: 'defaultTheme'
 buttons: [
    {addClass: 'btn btn-primary', text: 'Ok', onClick: function($noty) {

        // this = button element
        // $noty = $noty element

        $noty.close();
        noty({text: 'You clicked "Ok" button', type: 'success'});
      }
    },
    {addClass: 'btn btn-danger', text: 'Cancel', onClick: function($noty) {
        $noty.close();
        noty({text: 'You clicked "Cancel" button', type: 'error'});
      }
    }
  ]


    })


}
```

Comment: there's a comma missing `theme: 'defaultTheme',`
correct that and try again

Answer (score 0):

comma missing between theme:'defaultTheme' and buttons.